# Django nav-pills navigation doesn't work

Tags: css, django, twitter-bootstrap

I'm a newbie in Django and bootstrap. I'm trying to create a tabsheet panel with 2 tab. Each one contains a table. Here it's my code

```
{% extends "layouts/main.html" %}

{% block content %}

<div class="container-fluid bg-dark">
    <div class="container text-center menu-meals">
        <ul class="nav nav-pills center-pills">
            <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#deputati">Deputati</a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a href="#senatori">Senatori</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="my-tab-content" class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane active" id="deputati">
        <h1>Lista Deputati Legislatura Corrente</h1>
        <table class="table">
            <tr>
                <th>Gruppo Parlamentare</th>
                <th>Deputato</th>
            </tr>
            {% for deputato in deputati %}
            <tr>
                <td>{{ deputato.sigla_gruppo_parlamentare }}</td>
                <td>{{ deputato.nome }} {{ deputato.cognome }}</td>
            </tr>
            {% endfor %}
        </table>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="senatori">
        <h1>Lista Senatori Legislatura Corrente</h1>
        <table class="table">
            <tr>
                <th>Gruppo Parlamentare</th>
                <th>Senatore</th>
            </tr>
            {% for senatore in senatori %}
            <tr>
                <td>{{ senatore.nome_gruppo_parlamentare }}</td>
                <td>{{ senatore.nome }} {{ senatore.cognome }}</td>
            </tr>
            {% endfor %}
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

But when i click on a tab it the content doesn't change.. what i have forgotten?

Comment: You forgot to load js files in section media.

Comment: which js files i need?